# 'Unknown Compiler Option lib' in VSTS of Angular 2 Application using VS 2015

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had developed simple angular 2 application with typescript 2.0 version in visual studio 2015 by using below link.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Then after, I configured the DEVOPS for that application means when every I check in the code into my team project available in team foundation server using visual studio 2015. it will automatically start build for my application at that time I got exception like "**Unknown Compiler Option lib**" this below figure.

[image]

Please tell me how to resolve the above issue.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today after manually installing the latest version of TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593. 
To solve this, Go the source folder of your project, which for me is C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\. Open the file ends with .csproj and changes the line

`<TypeScriptToolsVersion>older_version_number</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`

to

`<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.9</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`

Answer (score 16):

I was having this same issue. I opened the .cproj file and changes the line
`<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`

to

`<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`

and everything worked